# When single " in \textit{} happen error

Tags: xetex

tex msg: `\textit{asdasda " }`

env: `\documentClass{customize class}`, I don't adjust textit command in own documentClass.

```
error msg: Extra },or forgotten \endgroup.
```

doubt: May be caused by that I defined some font in my documentClass.

Comment: Please give your MWE.

Comment: You are presumably using a babel shorthand so for example `"` is defined so that `"o` makes `ö`  But you should (almost) never use `"` as text in latex, use `''`  or `\`\``

Comment: @Stephen Sorry, the class I defined is too complex to raise own MWE

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thx your answer.I just tried it, and it does exist what you said. I am going to change the plan.

Answer (score 1):

You are presumably using a babel shorthand so for example `"` is defined so that `"o` makes `ö`  so `..."}` generates the error you show as it is looking for an argument such as `o` but finds the end of group `}`